# File upload only allowing one upload at a time

Tags: files

I'm having a problem with the File widget. I have created a content type with a file field that allows unlimited values. When I upload a file I am expecting to be able to immediately upload another file.

[image: expected]

but what actually happens is the upload box disappears, meaning I have to save the node and re-edit it in order to upload another file

[image: actual]

both these example have exactly the same content type settings, both running the same version of Drupal. I'm not getting any JS errors or anything. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I had a semi-similar issue a while ago and it was javascript related. [Browse link is missing for 2nd file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2280397)

Comment: I agree with @J.Reynolds. You should check js errors. If you will try with "clean" drupal installation, you will see new field immediately

Comment: I know, I'm pretty sure it is a JS issue but I get literally no error in the console, tried both Chrome and Firefox. Absolutely nothing, not even a warning